# Enhance generated DDL of EclipseLink

Tags: sql, eclipselink, ddl

Is it possible to change the generated DDL statements of EclipseLink during the creation process? In the persistence.xml I use the table-creation-suffix, but it adds only some things to the CREATE TABLE statements. There are also a lot of ALTER TABLE statements, which I can not change. Something like a table-alteration-suffix would be nice.

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.table-creation-suffix" value=";" />
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="sql-script" />
<property name="eclipselink.application-location" value="/path" />
<property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="create.sql" />
<property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="drop.sql" />
```